# Spring Cloud Data Flow (Kubernetes)- Stream deploy fails with an error: Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

During Stream deploy in SCDF (Kubernetes) app fail with following error:

> Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server

Comment: fix: one of the possible reason the header data is incorrect or not passed properly

Comment: Hi, which header data are you referring to?

Comment: The header data sent to external API. Correcting it fixed the issue